# Publish and Debug ionic 3 app on windows simulator without vs 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

TLDR: ionic 3 app, cordova 8, windows 10. cordova-platform is android and windows. Can run on android simulator and devices with VS Code. VS 2017 forces cordova 6.3.1 and doesn't work with cordova 8, but is needed for UWP (is it?). Would like to run ionic 3 app as UWP in windows simulator without usage of VS 2017. How? :/

---

I am working on an ionic 3 app. I installed the v8 of the cordova cli and I can run and debug the app with VS Code on Android. I use the Visual Studio Emulator for Android which works great.

I also want to run and debug the app build as a UWP-App. I can do that with Visual Studio 2017 with installed Tools for Apache Cordova - but it forces cordova 6.3.1. If I open the project with VS 2017 and I check the config.xml I can choose between cordova 6.3.1 (comes shipped with VS 2017) or the global cordova cli (which is my installed v8). If I set the global cli I can start the UWP-App in a Simulator. If I close VS, reopen the project it tells me that it's not compatible and I need to choose if the project should be converted. If I say yes the project is set to cordova cli 6.3.1 and older cordova-android and cordova-windows packages are added.

Of course, I do not want that (mess with config.xml, use older versions). I would like to use the cordova/ionic cli to start a UWP-App without Visual Studio 2017.

How can I do that? Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to use the ionic cli to start a UWP-App inside an simulator. But I was able to get VS 2017 work with ionic 3 (and VS 2017 starts the UWP-App inside an Simulator)!

To let VS 2017 work with a global cordova 8 installation you need to:

1. Force cordova toolsetVersion to 8.0.0 (https://github.com/hamburml/ionic3-vs2017-blank-template/blob/master/ion3/config.xml#L84)
2. Set your global node v8 or higher installation as external tool (Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Web Package Management) and move it to the top. VS doesn't use the old node anymore.

See https://github.com/hamburml/ionic3-vs2017-blank-template